# PHP is generating wrong next payment date from 29 Dec onward

Tags: php, date

I use below logic in PHP to generate next payment date based on proration for my subscriptions:

```
// calculating next payment date
$today = date('d');
$checkDate = '15';
if ($today >= $checkDate) {
    // subscription purchase after 15.
    $nextPaymentDate = date('Y-m-01', strtotime('+2 month'));
} else {
    // subscription purchase before 15.
    $nextPaymentDate = date('Y-m-01', strtotime('next month'));
}
```

Basically when a customer is purchasing a subscription before date 15, next payment date should be set to first date of the next month. Else it should be set to first date of next to next month.

**This logic was working till yesterday (upto 28 Dec 2014)**. As expected before 15 Dec I got `2015-01-01`. And after 15 Dec I got `2015-02-01`. But from today I am getting nextPaymentDate as `2015-03-01`.

I also tried

```
// ....
if ($today >= $checkDate) {
    // subscription purchase after 15.
    $nextPaymentDate = date('Y-m-01', strtotime('next month'));
    $nextPaymentDate = date($nextPaymentDate, strtotime('next month'));
// ....
```

But it gives the same result :(

I guess this issue might be occurring because there is no 29 or 30 or 31 Feb. If this assumption is correct this issue might be there for all 31 st days too.

What should I do? Please help me out.

Comment: 29th December + 2 months is 1st March, and this is not wrong. Why do you think it is? What date should it be?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look. Expected output is `2015-02-01`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the math starting from the first day of the current month:

```
date("Y-m-01", strtotime(date("Y-m-01")." +2 months"));
```

Comment: `date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-01")." +2 months"))`?

Comment: Agree with this but you have several ways possible like: `date('Y-m-01', strtotime('first day of +2 month'));`

Comment: I just tried `date('Y-m-01', strtotime('+60 days'));` and it's working!  Am I missing any corner case here?

Comment: I ran 3 kinds of codes in a for loop (2014-01-01 to 2014-12-31). 1. [My code](https://bpaste.net/raw/3fdfdb6c3a0b) gives incorrect result   2. [Code from answer](https://bpaste.net/raw/11372904adde) gives correct result   3. [Code with 60 days](https://bpaste.net/raw/926fcfe00d99) gives incorrect result. Then accepted the answer.